# Generate keystore p12 and truststore p12 files

Tags: openssl, keystore, keytool, truststore

I have ca.crt, client.crt and client.key file, can anyone explain how I can generate keystore.p12 and truststore.p12 file?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I was able to solve this. Posting answer for reference.

Step 1: Generate keystore.p12 from ca.crt, client.crt and client.key files

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key -certfile ca.crt -out keystore.p12
```

Step 2: Generate truststore.JKS from keystore.p12 file

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore truststore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Now, we have truststore file but, its in JKS format, lets convert it into .p12

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore truststore.jks -destkeystore truststore.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12
```

That's it you should have keystore.p12 and truststore.p12 file now.
When you will be running these commands it will ask you to enter the source and destination passcodes, you can enter the .same value in both.